# SQL SUM function to get inventory balance

Tags: sql, sum

UPDATE :

I have 2 locations to sell products , each location has 1 table ... i got balance for each location shown in image below ... now I want to Sum balances in one balance as total, I want to get full Balance for items (SUM balance for 2 locations ) ... need your help
[image]

I used this query to get balance shown above

```
Select item_id , sum(purchase)-sum(sales)as total from location_1  group by item_id 
HAVING sum(purchase)-sum(sales) <> 0
UNION ALL
Select item_id,  sum(purchase)-sum(sales) as total from location_2  group by item_id, 
HAVING sum(purchase)-sum(sales) <> 0
```

Comment: post some sample data what you have and required output

Comment: A) Please update your sample data. It's displaying as html code instead of text.  `I tried many many queries but no results`  B) Please provide a [mre] and the expected results.  Use a tool like https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: I am sorry I am new in this site ... I cant use page functions like codes .. ect

Comment: Please show what you tried to do

Comment: `I cant use page functions like codes` Just paste text and use the code button `{ }` (or indent 4 spaces). You should always be able to post code as text.

Comment: @PHPbeginner Just paste the code you tried and sample data anyone will format that and also you can see edit help which can be accessed in edit panel at top right corner by clicking on '?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get rid of the number at the end of the itemid column from the tables, then union them.

```
SELECT t.itemid, sum(purchase)- sum(sales) as balance
FROM (
      SELECT left(itemid, length(itemid) -1) as itemid, 
             sales, 
             purchase 
      FROM Location_1
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT left(itemid, length(itemid) -1) as itemid,
             sales,
             purchase
      FROM Location_2
     ) AS t
     GROUP BY t.itemid;
```

[db fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/guogUF56YVWStq4JfK4zJ1/1)